# How do I install GCC on a system with no compiler?

Tags: compiling, embedded, gcc

I've been messing around with my NAS which runs on Linux. I have root access, but there is no compiler. I seem to remember something about being able to compile on another system, but I'm not certain.

```
root@LSB1:~# uname -a
Linux LSB1 2.6.22.18-88f6281 #50 Tue Dec 22 18:06:23 JST 2009 armv5tejl unknown
```

Comment: If this is a commercial NAS that runs Linux, the GPL may not compel them to give you compiler source (IANALicenseExpert), but it may well predispose them to give you the goods if asked nicely.

Comment: What distro are you running?  Check the documentation for the distro's package manager.  For me "yum install gcc" would do it.  No need to compile anything.

Comment: It is indeed a commercial NAS with embedded linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cross-compiling may be the solution for you It allows you to compile executables for one architecture on a system of a different architecture.  [Here's an introduction](http://www.landley.net/writing/docs/cross-compiling.html)

Comment: This may even be the only solution as the NAS may not have enough system storage and RAM to build anything. Compiling will also be much faster.

Comment: I selected this as the answer since cross-compiling is what I need to do, but the link doesn't explain *how*.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your platform is included in http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a binary distribution available for your NAS? For example there are binary packages available for [DNS323](http://wiki.dns323.info/), not to mention that you can [install Debian](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/orion/d-link/dns-323/) on it.

Answer (score -1):

A distro without a package for GCC would be extraordinarily unlikely!  You should not have to compile it, in other words, you can just use a package manager.

Comment: Its a commercial NAS with an embedded linux. They usally don't come with any package management.

Comment: OH...okay.  Seems I have much more to learn about "NAS."