# Install Compiler, GCC, in SCO

Tags: software-installation, gcc, sco

I am having difficulty trying to install the GCC compiler in SCO, but can't get it to work.

I have used an FTP to transfer some files (`.tar.gz`) to `/u/test/installgnu/` and I extracted the files, but that is really the furthest I got.

I had a look at this post: [How do I install GCC on a system with no compiler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-do-i-install-gcc-on-a-system-with-no-compiler), but that doesn't help as SCO is very different to linux (well it is to me).

Here is the list of the files I downloaded from an FTP site: [Skunkware/osr5/devtools/gcc/](ftp://ftp2.sco.com/pub/skunkware/osr5/devtools/gcc/). So looking at those, I downloaded them all, and into the machine. But now I don't know where to go from here.

I am running SCO OpenServer 5.0.7

Comment: Firstly, which architecture SCO on? If your architecture use EABI formatting use "architecture-name EABI cross compiler" on another machine for compilation. SCO is not Linux and you use strictly unix toolchains for cross compilation and also this does not mean "none-linux" keyword you can see on internet search. Compile all and copy to your path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcc-98q2-dist.tar.gz` contains a GCC installation image, that is, a tarred-up installation of GCC. All you need to do is untar it to the root directory:

```
cd /
tar xzvf gcc-98q2-dist.tar.gz
```

But I hope you won't be using a GCC version from 1998. `gcc-2.95.2pl1-dist.tar.gz` seems to be a *tad* newer, but still old (1999). Anyway, if you need a newer version, you can bootstrap it with that compiler.

Comment: Ok, I have extracted the one you suggested - but I went into the tar file path (/u/test/installgnu/gcc/) and then extracted it - as that is where the tar file is. What happens now? All the files were extracted into /dev/. Do I now need to enable GCC?

Comment: Nevermind. I have now find out, after scratching around, that it unzips the files straight into the folder you unzipped the files from. I then had to use SCOADMIN to install the software.

Comment: I do apologise for reviving this, but I had lost my previous virtual machine, so started a new one. When I type: `tar xzvf gcc-98q2-dist.tar.gz` I get the following error back: `tar: z: unknown option`. I don't understand why it is saying that :/

Comment: @kevdog777: I know this is ancient Q but the reason for the error is that SCO Unix tar doesn't have the z (compress) option. You would have to install either GNU tar or GNU zip/unzip from skunkware. Alternatively, uncompress the file in Linux and transfer the resulting plain tar file to SCO Unix.