# Unzipping a TAR file, causing an error

Tags: tar, sco

I am trying to unzip a .tar.gz file using `tar xvzf`, as hhaamu said in his answer to my [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43177/install-compiler-gcc-in-sco) about Installing GCC on SCO.

When I type:

```
bash-3.1$ tar xzf gcc-2.95.2pl1-dist.tar.gz
tar: z: unknown option
Usage: tar -{txruc}[0-9vfbkelmnopwAFLTP] [tapefile] [blocksize] [tapesize] files...
    Key     Device            Block   Size(K)    Tape
    0       /dev/rfd048ds9    18      360        No
    1       /dev/rfd148ds9    18      360        No
    2       /dev/rfd096ds15   10      1200       No
    3       /dev/rfd196ds15   10      1200       No
    4       /dev/rfd0135ds9   18      720        No
    5       /dev/rfd1135ds9   18      720        No
    6       /dev/rfd0135ds18  18      1440       No
    7       /dev/rfd1135ds18  18      1440       No
    8       /dev/rct0         20      0          Yes
    9       /dev/rctmini      20      0          Yes
    10      /dev/rdsk/fp03d   18      720        No
    11      /dev/rdsk/fp03h   18      1440       No
    12      /dev/rdsk/fp03v21 10      20330      No
```

Notice the second and third line, where it says:

```
tar: z: unknown option
Usage: tar -{txruc}[0-9vfbkelmnopwAFLTP] [tapefile] [blocksize] [tapesize] files...
```

What does that mean, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Your version of tar on SCO doesn't provide the `-z` switch. Seems pretty self explanatory. What part isn't making sense?

Comment: Well it did work before, and wasn't sure if it was suppose to work, so I could successfully extract the file. To be honest I don't know what those letters all mean - I'm still new to all this.

Comment: Sure, it's an alphabet soup when you first start out. The letters after the command (`tar`) are all switches that tell the command to behave in different ways. I would take a look at the `tar` man page, and ask any questions here about things that don't make sense. If the Q seems too tiny, ask us in the chat room. Many of us congregate there 8-) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of `tar` doesn't apparently provide this switch/feature. So you'll have to do this in 2 steps:

```
$ gunzip gcc-2.95.2pl1-dist.tar.gz
$ tar xvf gcc-2.95.2pl1-dist.tar
```

For more information take a look at the man page for `tar` and also check `tar`'s options.

Comment: Or just `gzip -dc gcc-2.95.2pl1-dist.tar.gz | tar xvf -`